# How to use Subquery for Count Product Images in Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I am new to Laravel, How to do the following mysql Query with Laravel Eloquent.

```
SELECT p.*, 
(
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM product_images AS pi WHERE pi.productID = p.productID
)AS totalImages
FROM products AS p
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `DB::raw` to inject the subquery in the select:

```
Product::from('products p')
    ->select(DB::raw('p.*, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM product_images AS pi WHERE pi.productID = p.productID) AS totalImages'));
```

There's also the alternative of setting up a [**one-to-many**](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#one-to-many) relationship between the `Product` model and an `Image` model:

```
class Product extends Eloquent {

    public function images()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Image');
    }

}
```

After that you could fetch the image count like this:

```
Product::find($productId)->images()->count();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply... can i use pagination and where class in First method?

Comment: Yes, you can use both `paginate` and `where`, as well as any other method available in `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder`.